# ASP.NET MVC 3: IDepencyResolver is trying to get an implementation of IControllerFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Why is the **IDependecyResolver** trying to get an instance of **IControllerFactory** although I registered the **DefaultControllerFactory**?

**Global.asax:**

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(DefaultControllerFactory));
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new StructureMapDependencyResolver());
```

**Resolver:**

```
public class StructureMapDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    public static Func<Type, object> GetServiceViaDepencencyCallback = t =>
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(
            "StructureMapDependencyResolver is not configured!");
    };

    public static Func<Type, IEnumerable<object>> GetServicesViaDepencencyCallback = t =>
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(
            "StructureMapDependencyResolver is not configured!");
    };

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return GetServiceViaDepencencyCallback(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return GetServicesViaDepencencyCallback(serviceType);
    }
}
```

**Thrown error:**

> StructureMap Exception Code:  202 No
>   Default Instance defined for
>   PluginFamily
>   System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory,
>   System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In MVC3, the DependencyResolver (which is a service locator) is used to attempt to locate an applicable type. If it cannot find a type, then it resumes looking through using the legacy code, which is the `ControllerBuilder.Current` instance. The important thing here is that it checks via the DependencyResolver, your StructureMap container. MVC3 requires that the DependencyResolver returns `null` for when it cannot find a type, it won't be the framework's responsibility to catch any exceptions from your container.